# Manage Consumable IAP promo code

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I would like to know how to **manage** an **In-App Purchase** bought using a **promo code**.

In particular in my app I have a consumable that enables a feature, so I was wondering how to get the event that someone has bought that iap using a promo code, so that a can enable the feature.

Thanks