# In-App Purchase with Promo Code - and how to handle it

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, app-store

I've seen a few topics on stack**overflow** on promo codes handling: [Detecting promo code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931584/ios-detecting-promo-code-in-app-purchases), [Handling promo code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44336622/when-redeem-an-in-app-purchase-promo-code-my-app-doesnt-handle-it), [Consumable promo codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41639555/manage-consumable-iap-promo-code) and none of them have the right answer. There are some swift guides on how to create and redeem promo codes for in-app purchases, but nobody talks about what's happening later.

Redeeming an (in-app purchase) promo code on the AppStore:

- lets you open the app on successful redeeming
- notifies the transactionObserver declared preferably in the AppDelegate

Some people say it's all you have to do (and then when the user chooses payment there's suddenly no 9,99$ information, but something like 'Use promo code', which StoreKit handles behind the scenes). I'm afraid that doesn't work like that.

Should I handle it somehow in the AppDelegate - if there's a transaction coming right after the app launches (meaning that someone used promo code)? Should I present an alert telling the user he used the promo code, and unlock the functionality or add some 'gems' to his account (if it's consumables)?

EDIT: There are also these two apple developer forum topics: [Few people have the same problem - no answer](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/274958#274958), [Apple staff responded about where to place transactionObserver](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/204476#204476)

EDIT2: Or perhaps promo codes cannot be applied to consumable products, which are used once and cannot be restored (using in-app promo codes is based on restoring I've read somewhere?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who got stuck like me.

Indeed you need to declare a class (e.g. PurchaseHelper) importing **StoreKit** with **SKProductsRequestDelegate** and **SKPaymentTransactionObserver** extensions inside AppDelegate.

Then if the user redeems a promo code inside App Store - and he opens your app - '**updatedTransactions**' func gets called and it's the only time you can do something with the purchased product.

What I did was - **save an info/transactionId to UserDefaults**, so in the main screen user gets an alert like "You redeemed a promo code. Choose your favorite spot and click Purchase to get it for free".

Of course a better solution is to do enable the product right away in the AppDelegate. If your promo code gives the user 100$ (consumable) then you can just add it (but there's still question if he is logged in).

If you know any better solutions, please tell me.

Comment: I am trying this but the promo code never arrives in update transaction. Update Transaction is called upon launch of the app, but it doesn't contain the in-app purchase. Any ideas? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772095/redeemed-promo-codes-not-included-in-updatetransaction

Comment: would be amazing if you could post full examples of  your code. Everything yin the AppDelegate to make this happen and also the full 'updateTransactions' func. That would help a lot! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with offer codes but update transactions never fires once the purchase is complete. Any suggestions?