# Redeemed promo codes not included in updateTransaction

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have an application that integrates In-App Purchases. The in-app purchasing functionality in general works as expected for purchases that occur in app, and is also fully tested to work for purchases initiated in the app store (tested using "itms-services://?action=....")

I am enabling my IAPService as soon as the app is launched in the AppDelegate, and it is correctly calling updateTransaction as expected, but....

When I redeem a promo code it does not arrive in updateTransactions. It does contain other purchases that I have made, but no mention of anything redeemed through the promo code (despite getting a lovely message on the AppStore stating the redemption was a success). In fact, it never arrives from any other subsequent launch, or even if I subsequently call:

> SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

Any idea where I am going wrong? I have submitted a bug report to Apple in case it is something on their side but I am not holding my breath!

Comment: Having the same issue. I am validating subscription receipts on a server side and get empty purchases list for promo-codes. Is it possible that it is a temporary App Store issue? Maybe you know about any discussions on a support forum?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the Apple developer forums. No word on my bug report either. It's still not resolved on my side. I'm having to build my own custom solution temporarily.

Comment: It seems the promo codes can only be tested for production. Do you test it in the sandbox mode?

Comment: I have a similar issue. I make promo codes for a non-consumable item, the redeemed item is not in the app receipt - that I check whether the non-consumable is purchased. I can confirm this because the app is already in public and they cannot get the item even the redeem is successful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the same. It is still not resolved. I had to implement my own redemption system.

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I am facing the same issue. Redeemed in-app purchases are not being effected at the user end.

Comment: @venkat Unfortunately not. I ended up integrating my own solution, I make a call to our backend to check the user purchases (and redemptions). I think that is the solution Apple and co want us to take anyway.